# getting TLE from mouse maze in c++

Tags: c++

I keep getting TLE in this question.I have tried to use scanf printf instead of cin cout but it didnt work.Then,I tried another question which has same 
description,the only different is input N which means test case change from 1000 to 10^6.However, I got all AC there.I just cant figure out why.

following is the question

**Description**

Write a program that simulates a mouse in a maze. The program must count the steps taken by the mouse from the starting point to the final point.

The maze type is shown in following figure:

```
S$###
$$#$$
$$$##
##$$F
```

it consists of S (starting point), #(walls), $(road) and F (final point).

In above case, it needs 7 steps from S to F as following figure,

```
S$###
$$#$$
$$$##
##$$F
```

and the mouse can move in the four directions: up, down, left, right. There may be more than one way to reach final point, the program only need to print the least steps.

If there is no way from S to F, then print -1.

**Input**

The first line has an integer N(1<=N<=1000), which means the number of test cases.

For each case, the first line has two integers. The first and second integers R and C (3<=R, C<=500) represent the numbers of rows and columns of the maze, respectively. The total number of elements in the maze is thus R x C.

The following R lines, each containing C characters, specify the elements of the maze.

**Output**

Print out the least steps for each case, and there is a new line character at the end of each line.

```
Sample Input
3
4 5
S$###
$$#$$
$$$##
##$$F
4 5
S$$##
#$$$#
#$#$#
#$$$F
4 5
##S$#
$##$$
$$$##
#F###

Sample Output
7
7
-1
```

following is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;
int least_step;
void maze(char a[501][501],int,int,int,int,int);

#define wall '#'

int main(){

    int ncase;
    cin>>ncase;
    char a[501][501];
    while(ncase--){
          int num1,num2;
          cin>>num1>>num2;
          least_step = INT_MAX;
          int si,sj;
          for(int i=0;i<num1;i++){
              for(int j=0;j<num2;j++){
                  cin >> a[i][j];
                  if(a[i][j]=='S'){
                     si = i;
                     sj = j;
                  }
              }
          }

          maze(a,si,sj,num1,num2,0);

          if(least_step==INT_MAX){
             least_step = -1;
          }

          cout<<least_step<<endl;
    }

   return 0;
}

void maze(char a[501][501],int i,int j,int num1,int num2,int step){

    if(a[i][j] == 'F'){
       if(step<least_step){
         least_step = step;
       }
       return;
    }

    a[i][j] = wall;

    if(i+1<num1&&a[i+1][j] != wall){
       maze(a,i+1,j,num1,num2,step+1);
    }
    if(j+1<num2&&a[i][j+1] != wall){
       maze(a,i,j+1,num1,num2,step+1);
    }
    if(i-1>=0&&a[i-1][j] != wall){
       maze(a,i-1,j,num1,num2,step+1);
    }
    if(j-1>=0&&a[i][j-1] != wall){
       maze(a,i,j-1,num1,num2,step+1);
    }

    a[i][j] = '$';

   return;
}
```

Comment: You need a better algorithm.

Comment: You are searching for all possible pathes and it may be too slow, for example when all blocks except the start and goal are `$`. You can solve this problem via breadth first search, for example.

Comment: Profile.  Measure the timings of different sections of your code.  Profile.  Only input and output when needed.  Profile.  Use block input or output.  Profile or Benchmark.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Actually, no, don't profile just yet. A program will crash on a 500x500 empty maze, and take infinite amount of time (many orders of magnitude more than the age of the Universe) on a 500x2 empty maze. Come up with a reasonable algorithm, test on obvious inputs, then maybe profile.